# CAAnimation not working as expected on CALayer

Tags: ios, caanimation, cashapelayer

I am trying to animate the the appearance and then the disappearance of a `UIBezierPath` in a `CAShapeLayer`.

How I would like to do it is that at start, the path would be invisible by setting `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` to 0. Then, in my `animate` method I would do a `CABasicAnimation` with setting the `strokeEnd` to 1, and after this is done, another animation where I set the `strokeStart` to 1, so the path would disappear again. Here is what I've tried:

```
- (void)animate
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;

    CABasicAnimation *appearingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    appearingAnimation.duration = _duration / 2.0;
    appearingAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    appearingAnimation.toValue = @1;

    CABasicAnimation *disappearingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
    disappearingAnimation.beginTime = _duration / 2.0;
    disappearingAnimation.duration = _duration / 2.0;
    disappearingAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    disappearingAnimation.toValue = @1;

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.duration = _duration;
    animationGroup.animations = @[appearingAnimation, disappearingAnimation];
    animationGroup.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
    [layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"test"];
}
```

But the effect I am seeing is that the `appearingAnimation` is working properly, but as soon as it is done, the path instantly disappears without any animation. After this (`_duration/2.0` time later) the whole thing starts over, so it would appear that the `disappearingAnimation` has no effect.

I tried another approach, but that only worked if the path was on my `view.layer`. As soon as I added it to a sublayer and tried to animate that one, the second (disappearing) animation had a glitch in it. Here is my second approach:

```
- (void)animate
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;

    layer.strokeStart = 0;
    layer.strokeEnd = 1;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        layer.strokeStart = 1;
        layer.strokeEnd = 1;

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
             [self animate];
        }];

        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
        animation.duration = _duration / 2.0;
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation1"];
        [CATransaction commit];
    }];
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    animation.duration = _duration / 2.0;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Any idea why the first solution doesn't work at all, or why the second is only working properly on the `view.layer` and not on a `sublayer`?

Answer (score 0):

When animating a layer property, you will want to set the layer property to the end value before adding the animation, as the animation changes are only applied to the presentation, not the model layer. Once the animation is completed it will be removed, leaving the layer in the state it was before.

Both the first and second methods you have outlined worked for me once a layer had been created (missing from your snippet):

```
- (void)animate
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    CGFloat _duration = 2.0;
    CGFloat radius = self.view.frame.size.width/2.0;
    CGFloat startAngle = -(M_PI_2);
    CGFloat endAngle = (3*M_PI_2);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0);

    layer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                 radius:radius
                                            startAngle:startAngle
                                               endAngle:endAngle
                                              clockwise:YES] CGPath];
    layer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

   ... {animation code}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem of the value of `_duration / 2.0`. It may be the problem of floating number calculation.

Try not to halve the total duration but to make the durations of `appearingAnimation` and `disappearingAnimation` as the base duration:

```
#define DURATION_BASE 1
// You can choose the DURATION_BASE value whaterver you like

- (void)animate
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;

    CABasicAnimation *appearingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    appearingAnimation.duration = DURATION_BASE;
    appearingAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    appearingAnimation.toValue = @1;

    CABasicAnimation *disappearingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
    disappearingAnimation.beginTime = appearingAnimation.duration;
    disappearingAnimation.duration = DURATION_BASE;
    disappearingAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    disappearingAnimation.toValue = @1;

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.duration = appearingAnimation.duration+disappearingAnimation.duration;
    animationGroup.animations = @[appearingAnimation, disappearingAnimation];
    animationGroup.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
    [layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"test"];
}
```

When you want to change durations of `appearingAnimation` and `disappearingAnimation`, you just need modify the code like

```
appearingAnimation.duration = DURATION_BASE*1.2;

disappearingAnimation.duration = DURATION_BASE*1.2;
```